# iPhone sdk - Use a custom camera

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay

I'm developing an app that needs to take two pictures in a row. I'm currently using the iPhone camera but :

- I would like to NOT have the cancel
  button on the bottom left
- I would like to NOT have the preview of my picture (with the blue
  button "use").

What should I do ? Should I make my own camera ? I couldn't find an easy tutorial for a custom camera with only a "take picture" button...

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34433045/3908884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use UIImagePickerController with `showsCameraControls` set to NO and a custom view set in `cameraOverlayView`; this view can have whatever buttons you need on it. When touched, the button should call `takePicture` on the image picker, and when you're done just use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to dismiss the picker.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `UIImagePickerController` from code, adjust its properties, add an overlay onto it, and with you controller, control whatever you want on that overlay: custom controls, overlaying images, etc...

That gives something like this :

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

`OverlayViewController` is the controller that you must write to control everything you add onto the overlay.

`pickerReference` is a property you can keep to send orders to the camera. For example, you could call the following from an `IBAction` coming from a `UIButton` placed onto the overlay:

```
[self.pickerReference takePicture];
```