# How to customize the Camera view in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a requirement like add one circle to the camera view and capture the photo in that circle only.
How can I do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding a custom view on camera overlay view. This is the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can OverLay a view above your View
Please refer following Link

[iPhone sdk - Use a custom camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181590/iphone-sdk-use-a-custom-camera)

And for taking the pic in a circle you can take screenshot of that particular area when user slick on take picture button

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(vw.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[vw.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage * img UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

**Hope this will help you to build your own logic**