# Change the default image for the take photo button in iPhone camera

Tags: ios

Is it possible to change the button image of capture button in iPhone/iPad Camera? If it is possible, how to change its image and to set image for cancel button in camera? Or we need to create seperate toolbar to design it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overlay a view and on this view you can add buttons as per your need. You can add event on buttons to call `takePicture` on the image picker and dismiss it using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`:

So use **UIImagePickerController** and set  **showsCameraControls** to **NO**.

You can check this answer also for this : [iphone-sdk-use-a-custom-camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181590/iphone-sdk-use-a-custom-camera)

You can use this apple sample [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: so we cant change the button image in defaults?

Comment: Yes. For this you need to use an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using a custom overlay for UIImagePickerController.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = customOverlayView;
```

then you can use the `[imagePicker takePicture]` method to take the picture ,rather than using the default button