# creating custom camera with square view on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, camera

I am trying to create a custom camera experience on iOS and the following code snippet is as far as I got. Basically I want the usual camera view (i.e. with the following buttons: capture, flash, grid, front/back, cancel). But the only difference between the normal camera and mine is that I want **a square for the preview surface**; not a rectangle. And then, what you see is what you get (WYSIWYG) such that there is no cropping necessary; as the user would have taken a square picture in the first place.

I have also been looking at the library https://github.com/danielebogo/DBCamera but I am not seeing how to customize it to my end. Any help? Thanks.

MY CODE SO FAR:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Capture Session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

    //Add device
    AVCaptureDevice *device =
    [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //Input
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];

    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Input");
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Output
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];
    output.videoSettings =
    @{ (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };

    //Preview Layer
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    UIView *myView = self.view;
    previewLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    //Start capture session
    [session startRunning];
}
```

This is the only custom code in a single view project on Xcode

Comment: I'm a little confused - do you want to create your own camera-view from scratch, or do you want to use the built-in `UIImagePickerController` and just customize it a bit?

Comment: Either one would be okay as long as I get good control over what is happening. I have been looking at the Picker option as well; but there seems to be consensus that it is a poorer approach; which is why I have been researching the "from scratch" approach for the past few days.

Comment: Yes, the `UIImagePickerController` is not something I would personally recommend if you want full control. However, it is very quick and easy to implement. It does provide a fair amount of customization options, have a look at this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639188/ios-camera-with-custom-view)

If you want more options, go check out this demo program from Apple on the AV-classes [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Comment: small world: I already tried the AVCam. But when I tried to resize the `AVCamPreviewView` view in the storyboard into a square, itself it becomes the square; however, inside it is a smaller rectangle where the actual image shows up. Do you know how to get the actual image to fill the square (i.e. the resized `AVCamPreviewView`)? Or was I not supposed to resize `AVCamPreviewView` itself? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`? (may be typos there)

Comment: that's a bit above my head. Where would I set it? I search the product to see if the variable exists, but it does not. But you sound correct. Since when I tried to resize the AVCamPreviewView into a square, the view resized correctly but inside the AVCamPreviewView the camera feed shows up inside a small rectangle; it likely that some aspect ratio is set in somewhere but I can't find where to override it.

Comment: Yes, by setting the `videoGravity` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill ` on the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` you fix that aspect-ratio issue. This should be set in-code, for example in `viewDidLoad`. Without being sure, I believe you can set `(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.previewView.layer.videoGravity` if you're using the `AVCam` class from Apple. 

However, that class is way more in-depth than you will need, so I suggest watching/ reading another tutorial for example this one [link](http://youtu.be/Xv1FfqVy-KM)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options for doing what you want, either stick with and customize a `UIImagePickerController`, or create your own by using the `AVFoundation`.

The `UIImagePickerController` does provide a fair bit of customization options, and this similar thread has some good information on that: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639188/ios-camera-with-custom-view).

If you still want to make your own, I suggest heading over to the Apple Documentation and checking out this demo project called `AVCam`: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112). However, it's way more in-depth than you'll probably need so I can recommend this video tutorial as well: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv1FfqVy-KM&feature=youtu.be).

If going for the last option, I would like to mention that to make the "actual camera" fit the frame of your `previewLayer`, you can set the `videoGravity` on the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the resulting image match what you see in the preview?  This worked to give me a square preview layer output, but the image I get out of it is still the original camera aspect ratio.

Comment: @sak Is this solved "square preview layer output, but the image I get out of it is still the original camera aspect ratio"?

Comment: @iOSNepal  Can you share the solutions. I face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a custom camera can be a bit of a pain, but it’ll pay dividends given that you’ll really be able to customize your app experience.

The easiest way to do it is to use [TGCameraViewController](https://github.com/tdginternet/TGCameraViewController).

Using this `TGCameraViewController`, you can edit whole camera view. Also, It provides following functionalities:-

- Easy way to access album (camera roll)
- Flash auto, off and on
- Focus
- Front and back camera

Also you can refer [AVCamManual: Extending AVCam to Use Manual Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html) document for creating own custom camera.